# In ES6, How can i pass result of iterable of one generator function to another generator function as a argument?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

1. create a first generator function that generates the Fibonacci series up to the value.
2. Create a second generator function that will use the first generator function that will return Fibonacci series elements, store them in an array and pass that array to third generator function.
3. Create third generator function that will filter the even elements of the Fibonacci series i.e. replace the even elements in the Fibonacci series with '0'.This generator will take an array of Fibonacci series elements from second generator function.

**In a nutshell, this function will take a parameter that will be the maximum value that the Fibonacci series can have then, it will replace all even element from that series of array and yield the resulting array after filtration.**

```
function* fun1(num1) {
  var current = a = b = 1;
  yield 0;
  yield 1;
  var input = 3;
  while (input <= num1) {
    current = b;
    yield current;
    b = a + b;
    a = current;
    input++;
  }
}
it = fun1(10);
for (let num of it) {
  console.log(num);
}

function* fun2(num) {
  let array = [];
  array.push(num);
  yield array;
}

function* filterFn(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      array[i] = 0;
    }
    yield array;
  }
}
```

I want to pass `num`to `*fun2` as argument .In code `num` in fun2 is showing `undefined`. How can i achieve this? Also, how can i return array `*fun2` to `*filteFn`?

I edited my question for more clearance.

Comment: Why doesn't `fun2` use `yield`?

Comment: Can you show how you want to use this?

Comment: `filterFn` should probably yield the current element, not the whole array.

Comment: I edited my question with some corrections.But this code is still giving error in pipeline

Comment: *"and use other generator functions and pass that array to it and filter the elements"* are the other generator functions passed to the second function as argument? Are they hard coded? I find the specification of the second function unclear.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Have a look now.

Comment: I still don't understand `fun2`. It has no loop, so it only yields once. Why does it need to be a generator?

Comment: Is `fun2` supposed to generate a series of arrays like `[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5], ...`?

Comment: I had the feeling that `fun2` only passes the argument forward, converting an iterable (generator) into an array. eg. `const fun2 = (iterable, fn) => fn(Array.from(iterable))` If `fn` is a generator function then `fun2` also returns a generator. Then `fun3` can be passed as `fn`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to make the second function a generator function if you want to pass around an array. Also what's currently missing is that the second function *uses* the first function. You'd write

```
function fun2(num) {
  const array = Array.from(fun1(num));
  return fun3(array);
}

for (const val of fun2(10)) console.log(val);
```

However, if you want to truly use generator functions, then the `filterFn` wouldn't take an array, it would take an iterable. And you wouldn't really need the second function at all. Just write

```
function* filterFn(it) {
  for (const num of it)
    if (num % 2 == 0)
      yield num;
}

for (const val of filterFn(fun1(10))) console.log(val);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.